# HttpClient gets Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have a simple test client, written using .NET Framework 4.5.2, that I'm trying to connect to a customer's REST webservice.

The code itself is pretty simple:

```
using (var requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler())
{
    requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(myCertificate);

    var url = new Uri(myBaseUrl);

    using (var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler) {BaseAddress = url})
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var endPoint = $"api/MyController/Ticket/12345";

        var response = client.GetAsync(endPoint).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(JToken.Parse(content).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

To test this, I'm running IIS 10.0 on my local machine, and configuring SSL/TLS through the registry:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server\Enabled=1
```

When TLS 1.1 is enabled and TLS 1.2 disabled, if I run my client setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.1, everything works.

When TLS 1.1 is enabled and TLS 1.2 disabled, if I run my client setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.2, I get an exception:

```
MyTest: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
```

Which is exactly what I would expect.

And if I edit the registry to enable TLS 1.2 and disable 1.1, reboot and try again, if I run my client setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.2, everything works.

And if I run my client setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.1, I get an exception.

All of which convinces me that my test client is generally correct. It's setting TLS correctly.

So, then I put this on the client's machine and try to connect to their webservice.

We have a test webservice running on the machine I'm running the client on, so we only have one system's configuration to deal with.

When I run the client, specifying TLS 1.2 (which is what they want to use) I get an exception:

```
MyTest: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
```

So I try my client using SSL 3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2. No matter which I try, I get *Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel*.

Remember - this is trying to access a webservice running on the machine that I'm running the client on.

I checked the registry, and it certainly looks like they have TLS 1.2 enabled. And I know they've rebooted since they made the registry change.

They're running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 64-bit.

It looks, from where I sit, like TLS 1.2 isn't enabled on their machine, despite the registry and reboot.

Any ideas?

===

Just to make things confusing, when I access the site via Chrome, it works just fine.

Looking at the security details in Chrome's Developer Tools, we see:

---

**This page is secure (valid HTTPS)**

- Certificate - valid and trusted

The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by ...

- Resources - all server securely

All resources on this page are served securely.

- Connection - obsolete connection settings

The connection to this site uses TLS 1.2 (a strong protocol), RSA (an obsolete key exchange), and AES_128_CBV with HMAC-SHA1 (an obsolete cipher).

---

Comment: On the machine where it isn't working, what happens if you load that URL in Chrome?

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to have a problem.